# Why Stack uses 1-based index and not 0-based as in Array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, stack

Why the `Stack` implementation in Java returns the 1-based position from the top of the stack for the method `search(Object)` where the object is located and not 0-based position as we do normally in Array. Is there any special reason for this or does this solves any specific problem if that is not solved otherwise if we use 0-based index ?

Comment: yes, exactly.. the search(Obj) method in Stack class

Comment: I'm only guessing, but my guess is that it describes how many times you'd have to call `pop` to get the object.

Comment: Stack is one of the classes from JDK 1.0 and the API docs say that Deque should be used instead. The original API has its faults, many of the classes are very close to the related C libraries. Most likely they just happened to use 1 and once the API was released it was too late to change it.

Answer (score 1):

The *position* returned by `Stack.search` is from the end of the data structure, whereas *indexes* are from the start. Ranges are typically specified as half-open intervals, so it makes sense that the distance of the first element from the bound is non-zero.  The similar method `List.lastIndexOf` gives a value from the start of the list. The sum of values returned by `search` and `lastIndexOf` is the `size`.

@TJCrowder also points out that the `search` position matches the number of `pop`s you would need to do to get that element.

Note that the API docs state:

> A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is
>   provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should
>   be used in preference to this class.

**Edit:** Amusingly, it goes on to suggest this code (without bothering to link the `Deque` type):

```
Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
```

Due to poor decisions, `Deque` is a `Queue`. So you could but shouldn't write:

```
Queue<Integer> doNotDoThisFFS = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
```

The correct incantentation to write "`Stack<Integer> stack();`" is:

```
Queue<Integer> stack = Collections.asLifoQueue​(new ArrayDeque<Integer>());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#search-java.lang.Object-)

> ...this method returns the distance from the top of the stack of the occurrence nearest the top of the stack; the topmost item on the stack is considered to be at distance 1...

The method subtracts the 0 based `lastIndexOf()` from the `Vector` base class from the stack size.

From the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Stack.java)

```
public synchronized int search(Object o) {
    int i = lastIndexOf(o);

    if (i >= 0) {
        return size() - i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

If there was one element in the stack, say "A", it will be the top most element, so the distance from the top will be 1. `size() - lastIndexOf("A") == 1`